# Automated running of r-scripts

Tags: r

I know there are plenty of tutorials around concerning this topic but Im stuck and I think Im overlooking something.

Im playing around with executing r-files. So what I want to do is:

- Create an r-script
- Run the script through the command line

So i have this script (called "test.R"):

```
test <- function(){

  function(){
    x <- ("Hello world")
    print(x)
    }
}
```

And now I would like execute this script through the cmd line. However if I open the cmd line, move to the right dir and do

```
R CMD BATCH "test.R"
```

It opens the relevant R file but nothing happens! Any thoughts on how I can not only open the file but also execute it right away....

So when I run it I want the console to print `"Hello world"`

Comment: I think it's what you're missing 
"outfile 
the name of a file to which to write output. If not given, the name used is that of infile, with a possible ‘.R’ extension stripped, and ‘.Rout’ appended".

Comment: @MLavoie thanks for you comment. See my edits. Now it should work then right? But I still get the error...

Comment: I did something like that long time ago and it was working but I was using something like that "R CMD BATCH test.R output.txt" where the output Hello World will be printed in the output.txt file. And that's what the link I sent you says.

Answer (score 0):

I modified you test.R code to the following

```
test <- function(){
    x <- ("Hello world")
    print(x)
  } 

test() 'Calling function
```

Then in windows command prompt I typed the command

```
rscript test.R
```

and got this output

> [1] "Hello world"

Is this what your looking for?

Comment: yes that exactly what im look for. However when I try this I get: "'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program 
or batch file.". Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: There must be some problem with your path variable. Could you post the output of running the path command up here?